# Get error in django project?

Tags: django

My GitHub https://github.com/Loctarogar/line
Get this error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/

Reverse for 'dashboard' not found. 'dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name

settings
#authentification information
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')
```

I get this error when enter login and password and press "Log-in" button.

account/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r"^logout/$", auth_views.logout, name="logout"),
    url(r"^loguot-then-login/$", auth_views.logout_then_login, name="logout_then_login"),
    ]
```

shop/shop/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('account.urls', namespace="account")),
    url(r'^cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    url(r'^', include('goods.urls', namespace='goods')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: did you set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL on settings? also, explain when you get this error...

Comment: Show your urls.py where you include the dashboard url. If you include that `urls.py`, show the root URL config as well. Perhaps you forgot the namespace, and it should be `'<yourapp>:dashboard'`.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to use `reverse_lazy` in the settings. For example, `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the namespace `account`, so you need to include that when you reverse the URL.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account:dashboard')
```

Note that you can simply use the name of the URL pattern, and Django will reverse it for you:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'account:dashboard'
```